# Size of \tau and its low index with the most beautiful style

Tags: amssymb

Is there a `$\tau_M$` that to be the most beautiful in size of `$\tau$` and its low index?

Comment: Perhaps `$\tau_{\!M}^{}$`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti,How can I make a \tau with larger size?

Comment: It's probably easier to have a smaller `M`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want neither a larger tau nor a smaller M: just push the subscript down with an empty superscript.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\tau^{}_{M} > \tau_{M} \gg \tau_{\!\scriptscriptstyle M}
\]

\end{document}
```

where “>” stands for “is more correct than”:

[image]

Comment: I respectfully insist for `$\tau_{\!M}^{}$` (see my [previous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374230/size-of-tau-and-its-low-index-with-the-most-beautiful-style#comment925508_374230)).

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti No, I don't think it's better.

Comment: I think that $\tau_{\!\!_M}^{}$ is the BEST.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\tau_M\quad\mathrm{vs.}\quad\tau_{\!\scriptscriptstyle M}$
\end{document}
```